# Why Yarn/HDInsight has limit of 500 running yarn apps?

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn

Many times I have come across error in Yarn (HDInslight Linux cluster):-

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Queue root.joblauncher already has 500 applications, cannot accept submission of application
```

As per the MS site, the resolution is:-

```
Wait until currently pending jobs have completed before submitting more jobs
```

I feel this limitation of 500 jobs per cluster (which unfortunately also includes templeton jobs in case of Hive) is too restrictive. It means we can roughly have 200-250 hive jobs running per cluster. If we need to run more we need to spawn another cluster. This is weird. It means no matter how many nodes I have in the Yarn cluster and no matter how many cores & memory per node I have, I will only be able to run 500 jobs. There must be some solution to this.  Otherwise it goes against the very philosophy of distributed computing where we can increase capacity simply by adding more nodes to the cluster. It's like even if I have 10,000 nodes in the cluster, I will only be able to run 500 jobs on that cluster. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: The HDInsight documentation hints that the default YARN limit is 10,000 jobs in the queue, **of which** 500 jobs issued through WebHCat (*née* Templeton) -- seems like a sanity check i.e. WebHCat was never meant for heavy-duty job scheduling. Just out of curiosity: what kind of "jobs" do you submit through WebHCat, and did you consider other kinds of pipelines e.g. via HiveServer2 JDBC/ODBC sessions?

Comment: We are mostly running Hive jobs which we schedule through Azure Data Factory. There are bunch of pipelines in the ADF with activities of HDInsightHive type. We primarily use Hive, and so need ability to run many Hive jobs in parallel against a cluster.

Comment: corrected the exact error description in the main post.

Comment: @Dhiraj did you get an answer to this?